# Parse requests.post object

Tags: python, json, parsing, google-api, python-requests

How can i parse the entire output takes from a request.post object and extract only the "id" content, considering this piece of code?

```
import json
import requests

API = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url'
elem = json.dumps({'longUrl':'http://www.longurl..'})
output = requests.post(API,elem, headers = {'content-type':'application/json'})
```

adding `output.text` it gives me this:

```
{
 "kind": "urlshortener#url",
 "id": "http://goo.gl/..",
 "longUrl": "http://www.longurl.."
}
```

now I just need to extract the link in the **id** field, i also tried to put the content in a file and parse it as strings with `file.read()` but seems not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load it into dictionary using `json` module:

```
data = json.loads(output.text)
print data['id']  # prints http://goo.gl/O5MIi
```